# Is it possible to set a filter/filter property in the search query for Twitter API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter4j

Here's the query code:

```
app.get('/weather', function(req, res){
 T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'storm', count: 1000 }, function(err, data, response) {
    //don't want to filter here 
});
});
```

It's fully functionally(returning tweets), but there's a lot of tweets that don't have coordinates which are useless to me. Is there a property or something that will allow me to query the above but only include tweets that have coordinates that are != null?

I need to do this as a setting for the query, not filter it after I get the results.

Thanks in advance!

Twitter API 1.1, Node J.S.

Comment: Have you tried other search operators? See https://twitter.com/search-home and then click on the Operators link for all of the search filters. Check out https://github.com/ttezel/twit - there is an option to  filter the public stream by latitude/longitude

Comment: Doesn't allow custom search queries, uses public stream sadly.

Comment: that's too bad. Please post solution if you find one.